# Python Pass Checker - Point system wouldn't display after the password being valid. Pass Generator - Weak,medium,Strong Broken

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
import re
import sys
import string
import os
from random import *

def menu():
    print("Welcome To A Password Generator And Checker")
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input("""
1) Generate Password
2) Check Password
3) Quit
"""))

            if choice == 1:
                gp()
            elif choice == 2:
                points = 0
                print("""
- Requirments -

You Must Include:
~ Uppercase Letter
~ Lowercase Letter
~ Number
~ Symbol
""")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("""
Point System:
~1 Uppercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 Lowercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 From 0-9 = 5 Points
~1 Allocated Symbol = 5 Points
~If Has All Add 10 Points
    """)
                passwd = input("Enter Your Desired Password: ")
                passwdVal(passwd)
            elif choice == 3:
                os.system("cls")
                print("Goodbye")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                sys.exit()
        except ValueError:
                    os.system("cls")
                    print("Please select a legitimate option")

def passwdVal(passwd):
    while passwd:
        if (len(passwd)<8 or len(passwd)>24):
            print("Your Length Is Either Too Big Or Too Small")
            print("Try Again")

        if not re.search("[a-z]",passwd):
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",passwd):
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",passwd):
            break
        elif not re.search("[!$%^&()_]",passwd):
            break
        else:
            print("Valid Password")
            return True
            break


        while points < 35:
            if passwd:
                if 8 <= len(passwd) < 24 :
                    print(len(passwd),"Points Added - Length")
                    points += (len(passwd))

                else:
                    print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
                    continue

                if re.search("[a-z]", passwd):
                    print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
                    points += 5

                if re.search("[0-9]", passwd):
                    print("5 Points Added - Number")
                    points += 5

                if re.search("[A-Z]", passwd):
                    print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
                    points += 5

                if re.search("[!$%^&()_]", passwd):
                    print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
                    points += 5

                if points == 20:
                    points += 10

                print("You have {} points".format(points))
                break
            else:
                print("Not a Valid Password")


def gp():
    gppoints = 0
    print("""
Generating Password:""")
    generation = string.ascii_letters+string.punctuation+string.digits
    gp = ("").join(choice(generation) for x in range(randint(8,12)))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("I will now show you your new and improved password")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Enjoy")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(gp)
    while gppoints < 35:
            if gp:
                if 8 <= len(gp) < 24 :
                    print(len(gp),"Points Added - Length")
                    gppoints += (len(gp))

                else:
                    print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
                    continue

                if re.search("[a-z]", gp):
                    print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
                    gppoints += 5

                if re.search("[0-9]", gp):
                    print("5 Points Added - Number")
                    gppoints += 5

                if re.search("[A-Z]", gp):
                    print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
                    gppoints += 5

                if re.search("[!$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]", gp):
                    print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
                    gppoints += 5

                if gppoints == 20:
                    print("10 Points Added - All Of The Characters")
                    gppoints += 10

                print("You have {} points".format(gppoints))
                weakpass = gppoints  <15 
                mediumpass = gppoints  <25 
                strongpass = gppoints <35 
                excellentpass = gppoints <45
                if gppoints == weakpass:
                    print("Your Password Strength Is Weak")
                if gppoints == mediumpass:
                    print("Your Password Strenght Is Medium")
                if gppoints == strongpass:
                    print("Your Password Strength Is Strong")
                if gppoints == excellentpass:
                    print("Your Password Strength Is Excellent")
                break

            else:
                print("Not a Valid Password")




menu()
```

So for the password generator i tried to make it so that if the password is valid (containing all the allocated characters) it displays the point system regarding the password. The password generator works, however im trying to add the point system for that. The allocated points works however when im trying to display whether its a weak,medium,.strong password it doesn't work. I have tried numerous thing , none have worked so im resulted in asking help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @PM2Ring like when i enter a valid password it says "Valid Password" but doesn't display the points for the password. The generator, as you can see in the code i tried to create the weak,medium,strong  to check whether the generated password is actually weak,medium,strong

Comment: You need to add that kind of info to your question, don't bury it down here in the comments.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hopefully thats better

Comment: @PM2Ring can you please help me

Comment: In `passwdVal` you have `return True` after the `print("Valid Password")` line, so the function exits at that point.

Comment: @PM 2Ring what do you mean like do I create the passwdVal() underneath

Comment: If control reaches the `else` block in `passwdVal` that prints "Valid Password" then the function returns, so the stuff in the `while points < 35:` section won't get executed.